# Facebook like button - Circular redirect path deteted

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, canonical-link

Hopefully, someone here can give me some light. I have been researching this issue for a couple of days now, and cannot find a suitable solution.

First of all, I have used the facebook debugger and I understand what the error is, except that I am not sure how to fix it. You can see it here:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.viewrecalls.com%2Fshow%3Fq%3DGuidecraft%2520Mega%2520Profit%25204-in-1%2520Dramatic%2520Play%2520Theater%2520Toys%26amp%3Bu%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.cpsc.gov%2Fcpscpub%2Fprerel%2Fprhtml12%2F12131.html

I guess, facebook wants me to use either www.viewrecalls.com/show or www.viewrecalls.com in my og:url tag, as both of them passes the validation; however, if I do that, then the information displayed in Facebook will not be the information from the original link, and the user will be redirected to an URL that is not the original one or intended one. I am not sure how to resolve this issue.

My website queries an API and lists the query results. Once you click on a result from the listing page, it goes to a "show" page, where the details of the item clicked is shown. I have "long" QueryString going and one of the parameters is an URL. The QueryString is however encoded, and everything works perfectly, except that the facebook debugger gives me that validation error, and the button is not showing a count, it only shows 0 even though it posts to my facebook wall.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point your `og:url` tag (on the URL you're pointing a Like button at) to the URL you actually want the user to like, which has the metadata for that URL - image, title, etc

A circular redirect path almost always means an `og:url tag` on a page points to another page, which redirects (either by `og:url`, a `canonical` ref tag or a HTTP redirect) back to the first page or another page in the redirect chain.

Facebook's [Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) should show you the steps followed and where the redirect is

{edit}
In your case, i'm not 100% sure, but it looks like part of your URL has a `&` encoded in it, which may be the problem.

I manually curl

`http://www.viewrecalls.com/show?q=Guidecraft%20Mega%20Profit%204-in-1%20Dramatic%20Play%20Theater%20Toys&amp;u=http://www.cpsc.gov/cpscpub/prerel/prhtml12/12131.html`

and get an og:url tag of

`http://www.viewrecalls.com/show?q=Guidecraft%20Mega%20Profit%204-in-1%20Dramatic%20Play%20Theater%20Toys&amp;amp;u=http://www.cpsc.gov/cpscpub/prerel/prhtml12/12131.html`

which, when i curl THAT, has an og:url of

`http://www.viewrecalls.com/show?q=Guidecraft%20Mega%20Profit%204-in-1%20Dramatic%20Play%20Theater%20Toys&amp;amp;amp;u=http://www.cpsc.gov/cpscpub/prerel/prhtml12/12131.html`

it looks like another `&amp;` is being added into the URL each time and recursing - should the ampersand not be encoded in a URL as `%26`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. However, if you look at the facebook debugger results, you will see that my og:url is the same as the actual URL, and if you click on it, it goes to the page I want, which is the same page I want the use to **like**. Not sure what else I need to change.

Comment: let me check it out manually and i'll edit my answer with what's happening in your case

Comment: I think that must be it. That extra **&** is not really supposed to be added there. Thank for helping figuring this out. I think once I fix this it should work. Thanks again!